# Speech to text code stuck on "say something":

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am running speech to text code on python 3 by importing speech_recognition 
 and my program stuck on "say something" and showing

> sudo jack_control start  //terminal commmand

```
--- start
```

> sudo python speech.py //terminal command

terminal output:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
speak say anything
```

python3 code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('speak say anything')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("you said:{}".format(text))
```

I am not able to find the problem whether it is in jack or in code.

Comment: Do you have PyAudio installed?

Comment: I've tested your code and it works just fine. Here's my console output: `speak say anything
you said:hello`. Perhaps, you should check the jack and make sure the microphone functionality works on your computer.

Answer (score 6):

As per [official documentation](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst), the `listen()` method waits until the audio energy exceeds a certain level (indicating that someone is speaking), and records until silence is detected. If your microphone is picking up too much ambient noise, then `listen()` never returns because it keeps waiting for silence.

To remedy this, you can use `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)`:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print('speak say anything')
    audio = r.listen(source) 
    print("done listening")
```

You can also specify `timeout` and `phrase_time_limit` parameters in `listen()` to make it stop and return after a certain number of seconds even if no speech or silence have been detected.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print('speak say anything')
    try:
    # wait for speech for a maximum of 3 seconds
    # listen to speech for a maximum of 3 seconds
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=3)
    except Exception as e:
        # a timeouterror exception will be thrown if the timeout is reached
        print(e) 
    print("done listening")
```

In the initialization, it might also be a good idea to check for working microphones and explicitly set the device_index:

```
for device_index in Microphone.list_working_microphones():
    m = Microphone(device_index=device_index)
    break
else:
    print("No working microphones found!")
```

Comment: i tried your code, and i m getting this output: **speak say anything,
,listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start
done listening**

Comment: So it means it's not detecting any speech in the first 3 seconds. Are you able to record with your microphone from other programs (eg. arecord )?

Comment: Yes I can , I think may b there is some problem in jack

Comment: Do you have PyAudio installed?

Comment: i tried a python code to save speech into audio.wav, and that one is working but  not the above one

Comment: yes pyaudio is installed, i just run command on console import pyaudio and it worked

Comment: What's the output of `print(Microphone.list_microphone_names())`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191268/discussion-between-user11251362-and-glhr).

Comment: Please add the solution if you found one, I am having  the same problem.